# Apache PoolingHttpClientConnection Manager Release Connection when Response Entity becomes null

Tags: java, web-services, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` to pool the connections along with `ClosableHttpClient` and `CloseableHttpResponse` to make the service call. To read the sever response I am using  `EntityUtils.consume(httpResponse.getEntity())`. I would like to know how to release the connection when `httpResponse` becomes `null`. I have tried `releaseConnection()` (method of `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`) but it is not working. You can find the code below.

```
    String decision = "";

    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    try {
        HttpPost requestPost = new HttpPost(endpoint1);                                         requestPost.setHeader("Connection", "close");

        requestPost.setHeader("Content-type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        requestPost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        String xmlRequestStr = "Request=" + URLEncoder.encode(urlString);
        String soRequest = xmlRequestStr;
        requestPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(soRequest));
        httpResponse = client.execute(requestPost);
        decision = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(),encod);
        //connEvictor.shutdown();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Pooling Connection manager Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        //connEvictor.shutdown();
        throw new ToolkitException("Connection Manager Exception", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        EntityUtils.consume(httpResponse.getEntity());
        httpResponse.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`CloseableHttpClient` should not return a null response. On errors should raise an exception, so its safe to call `close()`. See [documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/CloseableHttpClient.html#execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,%20org.apache.http.HttpRequest,%20org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext))

Do not call `EntityUtils.consume(httpResponse.getEntity());` in `finally` clause because if error occurs the `close` method won't be executed

Please read connection eviction policy in http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html you can implement a monitor to close expired and idle connections that have been blocked or closed on server. The monitor calls `closeExpiredConnections()` and `closeIdleConnections(period`

Comment: CloseableHttpClient  is returning null when the request is getting Timed out and it is failing in httpResponse = client.execute(requestPost); step and going to Exception block  and i guess it'll come to Final block via Exception block if the error occurs.  If i am keeping the EntityUtils.consume(httpResponse.getEntity()); in try block then it'll not be  able to release the connection when the exception occurs. Right ? please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: If the response is null because exception is thrown you do not have to close or consume it

Comment: If i am leaving it then it is going to CLOSE_WAIT TCP/IP State.

Comment: CloseableHttpClient can be reused. Free resources when you d not need it calling `client.close()`

Comment: Why the connection should be closed? Read doc https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` connections are pooled on a per route basis. Probably the manager maintains the connection open until the resource is needed in the same route. Could you limit the max resources for a route to 1 and see if a subsequent request is using that connection?

Comment: ya those are using the same connection and i don't want to close the connection, just want to release it so that others can use the same connection and i am not able to release it because the httpresponse is coming null so EntityUtils.consume(httpResponse.getEntity()) is failing.

Comment: Please read **connection eviction policy** in http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html. you can implement a monitor to close expired and idle connections that have been blocked or closed on server. The monitor calls closeExpiredConnections() and closeIdleConnections(period)

Comment: Ya i have already implemented connection evictor, i have resolved the issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: Happy to help. I have updated the answer. Please consider to accept it for future use if it has been helpful

Comment: Can PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager  hold multiple CloseableHttpCLient ?

Comment: Yes, you can create several client and set the connectionManager. Connections will be requested to the manager and assigned from the pool